# Storage capacity missing on Ubuntu 18.04. System shows wrong free space

Tags: disk-usage

I have a disk of 128 GB with a partition of 84 GB where `/home` is mounted.

[image]

The image above says that 38 GB are free however, by running du, I have a result that seems to contradict it:

```
user@ubuntu-18.04:~$ sudo du -smh /home/*
16K /home/lost+found
14G /home/user
```

According to `du`, the total size of data stored in `/home` is 14GB. So if I have 84GB in the partition, I would expect to have something close to 70 GB free. If I run `df`, I have a result which is closer to the one shown at the first figure.

```
user@ubuntu-18.04:~$ sudo df -h /home/*
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb4        77G   41G   32G  57% /home
/dev/sdb4        77G   41G   32G  57% /home
```

It shows size 77 GB (why not 84 GB?) and used space 41 GB. So there are 41-14 = 27 GB used somewhere and I can't find where. I have used `Disk Utilities` graphic interface to try to find it, but without success. Does any one have a clue?

Comment: I think people have tried to explain this before at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/why-are-partition-size-and-df-output-different  Honestly, I think it is a bug in `gnome-disks`, but I rely more on the `df` utility for a more accurate reading of my drive usage.

Comment: I have seen this answer before asking here, but it did not provide an answer to my specific case. I have actually just managed to "solve" it. After restarting the computer, `$ df -h /home` now shows 82GB for the Size and 63GB Available. I have no idea why it was necessary to restart the computer in order to fix it and I must confess I'm very curious.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part of it.  Probably something that was deleted was hanging around until the restart happened.  I have seen that before here as well, but for the life of me, I cannot remember exactly the question that was asked, but I do specifically remember the solution being a restart of the system corrected the size reading.

Comment: I think this page https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-find-what-is-filling-up-disk-space-dev-vda1-is-100-full might have more of a clue where you could run `lsof / | grep deleted` from a command line and show recently deleted items.  This is the quote from that page "Sometimes if a file is deleted while it is opened by a process, it will not actually free up the disk space until the process is ended. This command will show if there are any files in that state."  Which would explain why a restart fixed it because the process if there was one had ended.